# Error while writing Beautifulsoup back over original HTML file

Tags: python, html, windows, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Could there be a problem with the encoding of the BeautifulSoup copy of my original HTML file?

I'm being told that I cant write to the file, because I must be writing a str instead of none.

Please see code and `TypeError` below:

```
#Manipulating HTML and saving changed with BeautifulSoup

#Importing libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Opening the local HTML file
site_html = open(r"C:\Users\rbaden\desktop\KPI_Site\index.html")

#Creating Soup  from source HTML file
soup =BeautifulSoup(site_html)
#print(soup.prettify())

#Locate and view specified class in HTML file
test = soup.find_all(class_='test-message-one')
print(test)

#Test place holder for a python variable that should replace the specified class
var = ('Testing...456')

#Replace the class in soup redition of HTML
for i in soup.find_all(class_='test-message-one'):
    i.string = var

#overwriting the source HTML file on local drive
with open(r"C:\Users\rbaden\desktop\KPI_Site\index.html") as f:
    f.write(soup.content)
```

[image]

Comment: Side note, but please use `with` when you open the file for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to open the file in `w` mode.

And, you need to either write `str(soup)` or `soup.prettify()`:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\rbaden\desktop\KPI_Site\index.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: I'm in love with you! Thank you so much... I will upvote and accept this as answer as soon as I am allowed.